# What does "Squelch" mean?

Tags: terminology, hearthstone

I have an option to Squelch or unsquelch the other player.

[image]

What does it mean/what does it do?

Comment: It's been around for a long time in Blizzard games. I know muting players was called that in Diablo 2 multiplayer chat.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Squelching mutes the other players emotes on your end.

Traditionally [Squelch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squelch) is used in two way radio operation and is used to cut off an incoming signal if the strength drops below a certain level.

In gaming terms it often refers to cutting off all communications from another player.

Comment: In the simplist terms it's an "Ignore" +1 for the origin of Squelch. =P

Comment: It's also traditionally a "Blizzard term," that is, Blizzard seems to prefer the usage of the term "squelch" to block communications from another player instead of other words like "ignore," "mute," or, well, "block." This dates back to the original Battle.net, with Starcraft, Diablo I, Diablo II et al. If I had to guess, it's probably because "squelch" is fun to say.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc Actually, in their recent online games, I believe they actually call it "Ignore".